# Filter on 2 items in Firebase database

Tags: firebase

I get data with this from a Firebase Realtime database and is working fine.

```
  Dim res = client.Get("Verhaal/" + rollTbox.Text)
            Dim std As New Student()
            std = res.ResultAs(Of Student)

            nameTbox.Text = std.FullName
            gradeTobx.Text = std.Grade
            secTbox.Text = std.Section
            Status.Text = std.Status
            Elftal1.Text = std.Elftal1
            Elftal2.Text = std.Elftal2
            Voetbal.Text = std.Voetbal
            Stand.Text = std.Stand
            Plaats.Text = std.Plaats
            Tegenstander.Text = std.Tegenstander
            MessageBox.Show("Data is geladen")
```

But i want to select on 2 items and that is not working . rollTbox is a number and BalId also.

There are multiple items with BalId and Multiple items with the rollTbox.

So i want to select the one with BalId "3" and where rollTbox is "1"
or select the one with BalId "4" and where rollTbox is "5"

```
Dim res = client.Get("Verhaal/" + BalId.Text + rollTbox.Text)
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the API you are calling in this code?

Comment: This is a bad idea , i changed it to sections . Verhaal , Verhaal 2 ...... Bit more work with classes but it is working